# jQuery remove h1 text

Tags: jquery, text

i have this html line:

```
<nobr title="New" class="testClass">
       <h1>ABC</h1>
</nobr>
```

How can i remove the text inside h1 or remove the whole h1 tag?

my last try:

```
$("nobr.testClass > h1").text('');
```

But this dont work

Comment: It works for me for removing the text. You might want `.remove()`, though.

Comment: What you have should work fine. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following removes the `h1` element:

```
$("nobr.testClass > h1").remove();
```

Though, your code should be working as written. Your error is elsewhere.

Comment: you are right, i had an error in my other js functions. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
   $(".testClass h1").text('');
```

and for deleting:

```
   $(".testClass h1").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the tag

```
$("nobr.testClass > h1").remove();
```

To empty the tag

```
$("nobr.testClass > h1").empty();
```